# How to open a Component in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a Home page (the default one) and I have a `Components` folder where inside I have a `Component` stuff called login-page where it contains html, ts, css, the thing is how do I open this Component from my `Home` page? I tried to do something like this :

```
import { LoginPageComponent } from '../../components/login-page/login-page';
```

and then in constructor

```
navCtrl.push(LoginPageComponent );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use plain components as page. Use pages as Page and components as Component. Create a Page with `ionic g page Login` Copy html, css, ts into this page and delete the component afterwards.

When you want to use the component you have to include the component with the selector defined in the @Component Section in the html of another component or page.

When your Component selector is "login-box" you can include the component like this in AnotherPage.ts

```
<ion-content>
   <login-box></login-box>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ModalController to push the components, for example:

```
export class AnyPage {

  constructor(modalCtrl: ModalController) {
     let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(LoginPageComponent);
     modal.present();
  }
}
```

But actually, I think you should use the Page instead of a component, like fastr.de told you. Run in your terminal the command "ionic generate page Login" and then you can use the NavController service.